# How to add Windows SDK to Eclipse C tools?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, sdk, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse Juno for Java developers and I want to add C/C++ functionality to it. I downloaded Windows SDK and tried to create Hello World C++ project. But it seems that Eclipse doens'nt see Windows SDK so I cannot compile my project.

Comment: SDK is different & ADT is different, are you able to see Android under window --> preferences

Comment: My question has nothing to do with Android. I want compile C++ project, not Android.

Answer (score 3):

Compile & build a C++ project with microsoft compiler is some chore work.But if you already installed some version of windows sdk, nearly a half of job done...

Well, I think you don't need to set up MS development environment, which is already in your path.

I can show you this process with eclipse neon version. I also assume you have eclipse cdt installed through the market place.

One thing you should do is installing the 'Visaul studio C++' setup.

Run eclipse, 
Open the "Install New Software..." on the help menu.

Type the url http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon, if you don't have any name with available site on it. Then Ok, you see the all available list from the site.

[image]

And you check the check box name, C/C++ Visual C++ Support.

[image]

Then, Make C++ project for yourself.
Run and enjoy it

[image]

I hope it is not a too late answer...

In case you don't have any environmental variables.
you can have main variables you have to set your env.

Open the windown SDK shell on start menu.
[image]

you can check that by running commands set lib, set include, set path in turn.
[image]